# GPU Memory for No gui Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, memory-split

### Context:

I am currently running a RPi 4 8GB with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on an M.2 240GB SSD. This system has no gui. I use it for GitLab and CICD purposes. On a x86_64, I know we can get a way with 0M for gpu memory in a Virtual Machine setup but not sure if there is something special to watch out for on the RPi 4. This is my first RPi.

### Question:

Could the system still operate at 16M or lower for GPU Memory to give more memory to the CPU tasks?

Comment: AFAIK the Pi4 ignores this anyway (at least on Raspberry Pi OS) and manages its memory split.

Comment: Correction to my earlier Comment. "On the Raspberry Pi 4 the 3D component of the GPU has its own memory management unit (MMU), and does not use memory from the gpu_mem allocation. Instead memory is allocated dynamically within Linux. This allows a smaller value to be specified for gpu_mem on the Pi 4, compared to previous models." See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/memory.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set gpu_mem to larger values, however this should be avoided since it can cause problems, such as preventing Linux from booting.
**The minimum value is 16**, however this disables certain GPU features.

[Memory options in config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/memory.md)

Answer (score 0):

I have set GPU memory to 1 MB in raspi-config and official Raspberry PI OS. 0 MB didn't work when I've tried to set.
I've no monitor connected and only connecting via SSH. This works flawlessly.

Comment: Pretty sure if you set it below 16, you get 16 anyway -- but the general point is true, the system is fine like that.